# Better way of using tables in android then innumerous if then statements (or switch/case)

Tags: android, excel, eclipse

I am developing a RPG character generator for a game using a purely random method (`new Random().netInt(100)`).
The system has 14 steps to create the character and some steps have between 1-13 dice rolls with table lookups. The problem is about half of the 'die rolls' have at least 5 rolls, each one being a lookup on a table, or another table.

Some steps are easy as there are very few options and coding in a simple switch/case of if/then loop is easy, if a little boring, but quite achievable.

In Excel I would use a vlookup to look up various tables, etc and get a simple result, but in Android, I'm wondering is there an easier way than manually coding several thousand if then statements for each "step".

Ive already simplified some table statements as there might be 5 options each using 1-20, 21-40, etc so simple maths will help, but other tables have been weighted due to RPG setting details, so changing them would give incorrect and inaccurate random results.

I thought of using SQLlite but numerous table lookups would result in very slow performance.

Currently the  class if getting very large with the switch and if statements but its not slow, just cumbersome.

I've got the data in pdf, excel, etc and can cut n paste the table data easily enough..

Am I missing a functionality of android that can perform table lookups (i.e. Excel "VLookup" functionality?) or am I doomed to write thousand of if/then  statements.

Answer (score 0):

Found this

http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

Add the data into a flat file, load it into the schema, and load it into memory. Access should be faster, so might be a better option....

I will give it a go and see..